# sql find max same subject in two table

Tags: mysql

Q. Let the size of a department be the number of instructors plus the number of students. Find the name of the largest department.

```
select dept_name
from(select dept_name,count(id) as people from instructor group by dept_name
union
select dept_name,count(id) as people from student group by dept_name)
having count(id)=(select max(A.people)
                  from (select count(id) as people
                        from (select dept_name,count(id) as people 
                        from instructor 
                        group by dept_name
                        union
                        select dept_name,count(id) as people 
                        from student 
                        group by dept_name)
                        group by dept_name) as A)
```

Instructor table view:

[image]

Student table view:

[image]

[enter image description here][3]

The results is Comp.Sci.

Comment: What is the result of your query? What is the expected outcome? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Note: It would be easier for people to help you if you created an example using http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Nobody likes having to recreate tables and sample data from screenshots.

Comment: The results is Comp.Sci.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student where dept_name = t1.dept_name) as total_member,
t1.dept_name FROM instructor 
GROUP BY t1.dept_name 
ORDER BY total_member DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested with my test sample database and it works!

It should work for you too. To include the duplicate record, you may consider to use UNION ALL like below:

```
SELECT MAX(total),dept_name 
FROM (
SELECT count(a.dept_name) as total,a.dept_name 
from student a left join instructor b ON a.dept_name = b.dept_name GROUP BY a.dept_name
union all select count(c.dept_name) as total,c.dept_name
from instructor c RIGHT JOIN student d ON  c.dept_name = d.dept_name group by c.dept_name) combine_table
```

Comment: be careful with UNION, when the dept has the same number of student and instructor, UNION removes duplicate records!

Comment: we may use UNION ALL instead.

Comment: Still, dept_name is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes, if you see count(a.dept_name) and count(b.dept_name)

Comment: Would you mind if I give you a challenge? Take a look here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647425/update-the-total-based-on-the-previous-row-of-balance

Comment: I mean :SELECT MAX(total),dept_name - here you cant just select the dept_name unless you use a group by or you put it in an aggregate func

Comment: Yes, we can. I tried and it works. Noted that group by were used in the subquery only. Thanks.

Comment: It can't combine two tables' dept_name in one and count all the number of people in the same dept_name

Comment: Thanks,Cheung Chi Fung. Now I fully understand your problem! Now, we work together to make this done! Please wait..

Comment: Try again. It should fulfill your question requirement.

Comment: Please let me know whether my latest edited answer is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select top 1 dept_name from
(
  select dept_name, sum(student_num + inst_num)
    from(
    select dept_name, 0 as student_num, count(id) as inst_num from instructor group by dept_name
        union all
    select dept_name,count(id) as student_num, 0 as inst_num from student group by dept_name
    )t group by t.dept_name
    order by sum(student_num + inst_num) desc
)
```